# ArrayList.size function doesnt reflect changes of first try but if i run the method again solves that

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, arraylist

I have a array list that takes changes on a AsyncTask that is called on a button click, after that i want to loop through the arraylist

```
 for (int f = 0; f < getid.size();f++){
                teste[f] = getid.get(f);
                Log.d("teste", "welelelelelele ?");
            }
```

but it cant because getid.size returns 0 so it doesnt execute(only on the first time i clicked the button), but why ? If i press back then click the button again it works, it returns the correct size and executes the for cycle.

**ButtonClick**

```
btnCriar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            SparseBooleanArray checked = listView.getCheckedItemPositions();
            ArrayList<String> selectedItems = new ArrayList<String>();

            for (int i = 0; i < checked.size(); i++) {
                // Item position in adapter
                int position = checked.keyAt(i);
                // Add sport if it is checked i.e.) == TRUE!
                if (checked.valueAt(i))
                    selectedItems.add((String) adapter.getItem(position));
            }

            final String[] outputStrArr = new String[selectedItems.size()];

            for (int i = 0; i < selectedItems.size(); i++) {
                outputStrArr[i] = selectedItems.get(i);
                Log.d("teste", String.valueOf(i));
            }

            Log.e("teste", "chega aqui ?===??");

            new Get(outputStrArr).execute();

            Log.e("teste", String.valueOf(getid.size()));
            String[] teste = new String[getid.size()];

            Log.e("teste", "chega aqui ?===??");

            for (int f = 0; f < getid.size();f++){
                teste[f] = getid.get(f);
                Log.d("teste", "welelelelelele ?");
            }

            for (int va = 0; va < teste.length;va++){
                Log.d("teste", "adadada ?");
                pls +=teste[va];

            }

            editText.setText(pls);

            Intent x = new Intent(AddCenario.this, GerirCenario.class);
            Bundle b = new Bundle();


            b.putStringArray("selectedItems", outputStrArr);
            String text = editText.getText().toString();
            x.putExtra("ola" , text);
            x.putExtras(b);
            startActivity(x);
            listView.getSelectedItem();
        }
    });
```

**Asynctask:**

```
 private class Get extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

    private final String[] outputStrArr;

    Get(String[] outputStrArr)
    {
        this.outputStrArr = outputStrArr;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... integers) {
        for (x = 0; x < outputStrArr.length; x++) {
            try {

                RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(AddCenario.this);

                String url = "http://brunos.000webhostapp.com/teste/obter_id.php?descricao=" + outputStrArr[x];

                JsonArrayRequest jsonRequest = new JsonArrayRequest
                        (Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                                try {
                                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); ++i) {
                                        JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                        id[0] = obj.getString("id");
                                        getid.add(id[0]);
                                        Log.d("teste", "chega aqui ?");
                                        Log.e("teste", String.valueOf(getid.size()));
                                    }
                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                error.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        });
                queue.add(jsonRequest);

            } catch (Exception ex) {
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
}
```

**Complete code:**

```
public class AddCenario extends AppCompatActivity {
String input,pls, kappa;
Integer podeIR = 0,x;
 EditText editText,esc;
String  idDivisao;
private String my_sel_items;
ArrayAdapter adapter;
String[] id = new String[1];
ArrayList<String> getid = new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final ArrayList<String> divisoes = new ArrayList<>();
    my_sel_items=new String();
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_cenario);
    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
    final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

    Button btnCriar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_criarr);

    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(AddCenario.this.getApplicationContext());
    try {
        String url = "http://brunos.000webhostapp.com/teste/listar_divisoes.php";
        JsonArrayRequest jsonRequest = new JsonArrayRequest
                (Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        try {
                            adapter = new ArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.custom_divi_mult,divisoes);
                            Integer i = 0;
                            String divisao;
                            while (i!= response.length()){
                                JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                idDivisao = obj.getString("id");
                                divisao = obj.getString("descricao");
                                divisoes.add(divisao);i++;
                            }
                            listView.setAdapter(adapter);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        error.printStackTrace();
                    }
                });
        queue.add(jsonRequest);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    } finally {
    }

    btnCriar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            SparseBooleanArray checked = listView.getCheckedItemPositions();
            ArrayList<String> selectedItems = new ArrayList<String>();

            for (int i = 0; i < checked.size(); i++) {
                // Item position in adapter
                int position = checked.keyAt(i);
                // Add sport if it is checked i.e.) == TRUE!
                if (checked.valueAt(i))
                    selectedItems.add((String) adapter.getItem(position));
            }

            final String[] outputStrArr = new String[selectedItems.size()];

            for (int i = 0; i < selectedItems.size(); i++) {
                outputStrArr[i] = selectedItems.get(i);
                Log.d("teste", String.valueOf(i));
            }

            Log.e("teste", "chega aqui ?===??");

            new Get(outputStrArr).execute();

            Log.e("teste", String.valueOf(getid.size()));
            String[] teste = new String[getid.size()];

            Log.e("teste", "chega aqui ?===??");

            for (int f = 0; f < getid.size();f++){
                teste[f] = getid.get(f);
                Log.d("teste", "welelelelelele ?");
            }

            for (int va = 0; va < teste.length;va++){
                Log.d("teste", "adadada ?");
                pls +=teste[va];

            }

            editText.setText(pls);

            Intent x = new Intent(AddCenario.this, GerirCenario.class);
            Bundle b = new Bundle();


            b.putStringArray("selectedItems", outputStrArr);
            String text = editText.getText().toString();
            x.putExtra("ola" , text);
            x.putExtras(b);
            startActivity(x);
            listView.getSelectedItem();
        }
    });

}

private class Get extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

    private final String[] outputStrArr;

    Get(String[] outputStrArr)
    {
        this.outputStrArr = outputStrArr;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... integers) {
        for (x = 0; x < outputStrArr.length; x++) {
            try {

                RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(AddCenario.this);

                String url = "" + outputStrArr[x];

                JsonArrayRequest jsonRequest = new JsonArrayRequest
                        (Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                                try {
                                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); ++i) {
                                        JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                        id[0] = obj.getString("id");
                                        getid.add(id[0]);
                                        Log.d("teste", "chega aqui ?");
                                        Log.e("teste", String.valueOf(getid.size()));
                                    }
                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                error.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        });
                queue.add(jsonRequest);

            } catch (Exception ex) {
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Sounds like web request isn't finished yet, so when you go back and click again, you get request is finally finished and you get your data.

Comment: See please: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Gudin, so what should i do ?

Comment: You could disable button initially, and then when the request is over enable it. That way user won't be able to click until request is finished.

Comment: Hint: your trace statements aren't really useful. Dont try to be funny - only log content that really helps you debugging your issues, like exact counter values and such things. Printing sutff like Log.d("teste", "chega aqui ?") just puts a lot of **noise** into your logfiles. Put relevant stuff into there, not things that HIDE what is going on!